# there is a event in Windows Phone 8 on that I can do song paused when I leave current page?

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I developing Application Windows Phone 8 that play songs mp3 in playlist with MediaElement.
I put Ads Admob in top of playlist, and when I play song I click on Ads and when I back to playlist I see that song closed.
I ask if there is a event in Windows Phone 8 on that I can do song paused when I leave current page?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnNavigateFrom event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom(v=vs.105).aspx)

Pausing song could not be sufficient. You should also persist song position and restore it in OnNavigateTo event.